# UnknownAttributeError when making an association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, join

EDIT!: 
Solved by @mellowfish
Turns out the Test database had not been migrated, and I was just migrating my dev database! I ran this code to setup my test database.

> bundle exec rails db:test:prepare

I'm setting up a food/drink app. I have *cocktails*, and *ingredients*, and I have a **has_and_belongs_to_many** relationship between the two. When I try to add "cocktail.ingredients << ingredients", I get an UnknownAttributeError.

I have checked all naming conventions of rails. I can add ingredients to cocktails when it has a *has_many* relationship for the cocktail model, however that does me no good; I need a *has_and_belongs_to_many* relationship with cocktails and ingredients.

```
RSpec.describe Cocktail, type: :model do
  subject do
    build(:cocktail)
  end

describe 'when adding ingredients' do
    context 'with valid attributes' do
      it 'saves successfully' do
        ingredient = create(:ingredient)
        subject.ingredients << ingredient
        expect(subject.ingredients.length).to eq(1)
      end
    end
```

In my console during byebug testing, I can see the empty associations::collectionproxy [] for cocktail. 
However when I try to shovel an ingredient in, it gives me the

> "ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError Exception: unknown attribute >'cocktail_id' for Cocktail::HABTM_Ingredients."

It is the same error for ingredients as well:

> Failure/Error: subject.cocktails << cocktail
>      ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError:
>       unknown attribute 'ingredient_id' for Ingredient::HABTM_Cocktails.

This is cocktail.ingredients return before shovelling:
"ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []"

This is ingredient.cocktails:
"Cocktail::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x000055e464d62628"

Comment: Have you run your migration to create the `cocktail_ingredients` mapping table? What is the schema for that table?

Comment: Migration is there,
up     20190822174002  Create cocktails ingredients
Here is the schema:
 
`create_table "cocktails_ingredients", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.bigint "cocktail_id"

    t.bigint "ingredient_id"

    t.index ["cocktail_id"], name: "index_cocktails_ingredients_on_cocktail_id"

    t.index ["ingredient_id"], name: "index_cocktails_ingredients_on_ingredient_id"
  end`
sorry for formatting trying to get this to look better @mellowfish

Comment: No worries. The migration looks good. It seems like you are using FactoryBot to build/create these objects. Can I see the factory definitions?

Comment: `factory :cocktail do    
  name { generate(:name)}
end
  factory :ingredient do
    name { generate(:name) }
  end
Thank you for your time @mellowfish

Comment: Try adding `ingredients { [] }` to your `cocktail` factory.

Comment: Also, could you confirm that your `cocktails_ingredients` table exists (and is correct) in your `_test` database (vs your `_dev` one)?

Comment: tried that out
  factory :cocktail do
    name { generate(:name)}
    ingredients {[]}
  end
Same error still. It's REALLY wierd.

Comment: You cracked the case! How do I thank you on here! @mellowfish

Comment: Added "answer" for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the mapping table was created in your test database.

From the output, rails is trying to guess at a schema instead of using what it finds in the database, which means it isn't finding the table your migration is supposed to define.